# How do you calculate the number of days between dates on different rows

Tags: sql-server, date, compare

I have a table with 3 columns: clientid, start_date, end_date

Each row is an episode of care, clients can have multiple episodes of care. I am trying to write a query in SQL Server which will display the start and end date of the latest episode of care only if it is 21 days after the previous episodes end date. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you looked at `DATEDIFF` and `LEAD`/`LAG`? Whave *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I have used datediff to calculate the number of days between dates but I do not understand how to compare the end date from one episode (row 1) with the start date of the next episode (row 2).

Comment: Why doesn't `LEAD`/`LAG` work for that?

Answer (score 0):

'I do not understand how to compare the end date from one episode (row 1) with the start date of the next episode (row 2).' is straightforward but you cannot use window functions in the where clause or the calculated difference - which means using a sub query (or a cte) to do the bulk of the work

```
drop table t
go
create table t
(clientid int, start_date date, end_date date);
go
insert into t values
(1,'2022-09-01','2022-09-01'),
(1,'2022-09-10','2022-09-10')

go

select * from
(
select *,
 lag(end_date) over (partition by clientid order by start_date) lage,
 datediff(d,lag(end_date) over (partition by clientid order by start_date),start_date) diff
 from t
) s
where diff = 9

clientid    start_date end_date   lage       diff
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1           2022-09-10 2022-09-10 2022-09-01 9

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

LAG worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).